# What is the correct way to define the loss function in tensorflow 2.+ in the following code?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am making a simple GAN neural network. My architecture is defined by two principal models a `Discriminator` and a `Generator`:

```
class Discriminator(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Discriminator, self).__init__(name='')

    self.h0 = Linear(num_outputs=hidden_size * 2)
    self.h1 = Linear(num_outputs=hidden_size * 2)
    self.h2 = Linear(num_outputs=hidden_size * 2)
    self.h3 = Linear(num_outputs=1)

  #We use the training parameter to take control the generator only can tune its
  #parameters.
  @tf.function
  def call(self, input_tensor):
    x = tf.tanh(self.h0(input_tensor))
    x = tf.tanh(self.h1(x))
    x = tf.tanh(self.h2(x))
    x = tf.sigmoid(self.h3(x))
    return x
```

and

```
class GeneratorModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(GeneratorModel, self).__init__(name='')

    self.h0 = Linear(num_outputs=hidden_size)
    self.h1 = Linear(num_outputs=1)

  @tf.function
  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.h0(input_tensor)
    x = tf.nn.softplus(x)
    x = self.h1(x)
    return x
```

Then I define some optimizers for each network and some loss function using lambda functions, in the following code:

```
#Optimizers
opt_discriminator = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
opt_generator = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

# Loop to the epoch
for epoch in range(numEpochs):
    epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    epoch_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

    batch_x = data.sample(batch_size).astype('float32')
    batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x,(batch_size,1))

    batch_z = gen.sample(batch_size).astype('float32')
    batch_z = np.reshape(batch_z,(batch_size,1))

    #UPDATE DISCRIMINATOR
    discriminator.trainable = True

    #sharing the parameters of the discriminator network
    D1x = discriminator(batch_x)
    D2x = discriminator(generator(batch_z))

    loss_D = lambda: tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(tf.maximum(D1x,1e-5)) - tf.math.log(tf.maximum(D2x,1e-5)))
    

    opt_discriminator.minimize(loss_D,var_list=discriminator.trainable_weights)

    #UPDATE GENERATOR
    discriminator.trainable = False

    batch_z = gen.sample(batch_size)
    D2x = discriminator(generator(batch_z))

    loss_G = lambda: tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(tf.maximum(D2x,1e-5)))

    opt_generator.minimize(loss_G,var_list=generator.trainable_weights)
```

However, when I executed I received the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-8cbc62f3482a> in <module>()
     24 
     25 
---> 26     opt_discriminator.minimize(loss_D,var_list=discriminator.trainable_weights)
     27 
     28     #UPDATE GENERATOR

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
   1269   if not filtered:
   1270     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
-> 1271                      ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
   1272   if vars_with_empty_grads:
   1273     logging.warning(

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['linear_21/w:0', 'linear_21/b:0', 'linear_22/w:0', 'linear_22/b:0', 'linear_23/w:0', 'linear_23/b:0', 'linear_24/w:0', 'linear_24/b:0'].
```

Can someone help me, please? I don't know what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using `tf.GradientTape()` for update the weights. In the following way:

```
def run_opt_discriminator(real_sample, z_noise):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    D1x = discriminator(real_sample)
    gen_sample = generator(z_noise)
    D2x = discriminator(gen_sample)
    loss_value = loss_discriminator(D1x,D2x)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, discriminator.trainable_variables)
    opt_discriminator.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))

    return loss_value
```

and

```
def run_opt_generator(z_noise):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    gen_sample = generator(z_noise)
    D2x = discriminator(gen_sample)
    loss_value = loss_generator(D2x)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, generator.trainable_variables)
    opt_generator.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, generator.trainable_variables))

    return loss_value
```

However, I would like to know if I could use the minimize function.